# System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. error

Tags: c#, excel

I`m getting an ArgumentException from the following code:

```
string strPath="C:\somename.xls";
startPath=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(startPath, strPath);
```

I found this code on Stack Overflow.
Link:
[C#:Copy protected worksheet to another excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293451/ccopy-protected-worksheet-to-another-excel-file)
 I don't exactly know what it is. Please tell me what it is. This code I'm building into an exe.

Lastly, I need to Copy one worksheet to another file.

What`s wrong am I doing? I deploy this in server.

Comment: C# specs [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=VS.71).aspx). By the way, why do you initialize the string filePath two times?

Comment: You assign a literal string to `filePath`, and then overwrite it with the result of `Path.Combine`. Where do you get `strPath`?

Comment: Also, where on Stack Overflow did you get this code? Could you like to the question/answer? That might help us understand the context a little better.

Comment: Sorry for a big mistake. Editted my post again. please check out.

Comment: @user2144293  also, try to avoid free-hand copying your code.  if you make a mistake doing that, you'll get incorrect feedback.  try to use  copy/paste

Comment: @SamIam: Thanks for the answer. "startPath" wil be the path of the exe as you said, and "strPath" that I pass will have path like "C:\New Folder\aa\bb\cc\somename.exe". Is this wrong?

Comment: @user2144293  what do you want `filePath` to be?

Comment: @SamIam: I thought this is a way we have to get new excel file. wat do you suggest for this? overall copying worksheet to new file. I want this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293451/ccopy-protected-worksheet-to-another-excel-file"

Comment: @user2144293 I'm not an expert on excel files, but I do know that all `System.IO.Path.Combine();` really does, is string manipulation.  I presume that it's a path where you want the excel file to be created at.  Where is that?

Comment: @SamIam: I got what i wanted. it`s just needed to be "strPath". rest is not needed for me.

Answer (score 11):

what that code appears to do, is it gets your working directory(wherever the `exe` associated with your code is), and combines it with `"C:\\somename.xls"`(which doesn't make sense.)

I think you might have intended something like

```
string strPath=@"somename.xls";
```

so assume you're running your application from

```
"C:\Users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug"
```

what that code would do is set `filePath` to

```
"C:\Users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\somename.xls"
```

---

the first thing I saw was

```
string filePath="C:\somename.xls";
```

`\` is a special character, for determining other characters.  for instance `'\n'` is a  newline.  `'\\'` is the actual backslash.

so, you want to escape your `\` with another `\`

```
string filePath="C:\\somename.xls";
```

or make it a literal string by putting a `@` in front of it.

```
string filePath=@"C:\somename.xls";
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
string filePath = "C:\\somename.xls"
```

You need double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with the code,

**First**

```
string filePath="C:\somename.xls";
```

`\` is a special character, for determining other characters.  for instance `'\n'` is a  newline.  `'\\'` is the actual backslash.

**Second**

`filePath` contains a root path, `C:\\`.  `Path.Combine` will just return `filePath` then, it cannot be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is in `startPath` parameter.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

If you trace your code, in `FileName` you will see a bad symbol character witch is illegal